# Create a check box for each row inside a power bi table

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I am trying to add a check box to each row inside a power bi table.
Post clicking I would want to lock/highlight the row.
I know this is pretty simple to create on a web page.

Could anyone please suggest any ways of achieving this in power bi.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of functionality is not available in Power BI. You can add highlighting to the row using [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) and/or add a [KPI icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-kpi)